# Bower not installing on zsh

Tags: osx-yosemite, homebrew, node.js

I tried both:

```
npm -g install bower
```

and

```
sudo npm -g install bower
```

The response is:

> zsh: command not found: bower

It is not install or not being found.

Comment: 'module.js:338
    throw err;' is the error I am getting

Comment: running node app.js getting module.js:338
    throw err;

Comment: `sudo` should not be necessary. Do you see the error immediately when trying to install, or afterward when you try to *use* bower? If it's after, a copy/paste of the installation log might help. Also check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555129/bower-grunt-zsh-command-not-found

Comment: I have my app.js file in "client/app/srcipts/app.js" moving to root to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$ npm config set prefix /usr/local
$ npm install -g bower

$ which bower
>> /usr/local/bin/bower
```

Comment: Basically, You don't have to install it general, You can only install it locally.